# HttpClient.PostAsync() request not reaching destination

Tags: .net, asynchronous, post, c#-4.0, concurrency

I am modifying the purchasing process of an e-commerce site, which has the ability to make purchases for multiple users and multiple products with a single purchase. Large purchases can occasionally take several minutes to complete, which the e-commerce site back-end would make the user wait for; not a great UX.

I am trying to make the site generate a JSON string and kick it over to an API which will do the purchase processing on a different server, and let the Site  continue on the the ThankYou page, without waiting for a response from the API. 
My challenge is, sometimes the Post doesn't make it to the API. I put a thread.sleep command after the postasync and that seems to fix the issue on my local machine, but I have concerns about the reliability of that solution.

TLDR; my goal is to make the code reliably send posts to an API without awaiting the result. This is something I have struggled with before and if there is a best practice to achieve the result, I have not been able to find it. Any advice would be appreciated.

See post code below; nothing fancy going on. Code lives inside an eventHandler function on the e-commerce back-end.

```
using (System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler(),false))
                {
                    var url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIURL"];
                    var reqBody = new StringContent(RequestData.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                   var task =  client.PostAsync(url, reqBody);

                    //increases chance of post reaching API before function ends 
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

> reliably send posts to an API without awaiting the result

This isn't possible. Reliable code *requires* `await`. Calling asynchronous methods without `await`ing them is a form of "fire and forget", and *by definition* fire-and-forget code does not care if (or whether) the operation completes.

One alternative approach that may work for you is to have a reliable queue and write to *that* instead of to the API. Then have a background processor that reads from that queue and posts to the API.

Comment: This wound up being an  easier solution than expected! Thanks for your insight!